# How to repaint colored text in JTextPane back to its default color?

Tags: java, swing, rgb, jtextpane, text-coloring

```
public void setJTextPane(JTextPane jtp, Color c, int from, int to) {
    // Start with the current input attributes for the JTextPane. This
    // should ensure that we do not wipe out any existing attributes
    // (such as alignment or other paragraph attributes) currently
    // set on the text area.

    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();

    AttributeSet attrs = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
    // Set the font color

    // Retrieve the pane's document object
    StyledDocument doc = jtp.getStyledDocument();

    // Replace the style for the entire document. We exceed the length
    // of the document by 1 so that text entered at the end of the
    // document uses the attributes.
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(from, to, attrs, true);
}

public void recoverTextPane(JTextPane jtp, int from, int to) {
    StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
    AttributeSet attrs = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, 
            new Color(51,51,51));
    StyledDocument doc = jtp.getStyledDocument();
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(from, to, attrs, true);
}
```

The purpose of setJTextPane is to paint a particular line of JTextPane between two indices. The function works correctly as expected. However, I wanted to convert that particular line of text back to its original color. So I basically created a separate function that converts that line to the known RGB. However, this does nothing to the text. Can anyone diagnose the issue with the code?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: -1 again without an MCVE/SSCCE

Answer (score 1):

```
SimplaAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(attrs, theColor);
StyledDocument doc = jtp.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(from, to, attrs, false);
```

You create empty attribute set, specify the foreground color and apply it without replacing the original attributes. Check the `from` and `to` parameters to cover correct fragment.

Comment: This piece above should be added to the recover method? This doesn't even modify the color??